# Protected access specifier giving unexpected compile time error in child class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, inheritance

```
// This package and class are in ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD.java file
package com.j2se.access_specifiers;
public class ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD {
    protected int protectedIntVar;
    protected String protectedStrVar;
}
```

I create another file where I extend this class for studying protected access specifier properties as below:-

```
//This package and class are in ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD2.java file

package com.j2se.access_specifiers_2;

import com.j2se.access_specifiers.ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD;

public class ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD2 extends ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD obj = new ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD();
/* Here on below line compile time error comes "The field ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD.protectedStrVar & ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD.protectedIntVar are not visible"*/
            System.out.println(obj.protectedIntVar+" "+obj.protectedStrVar);
        }
}
```

Now, to the best of my knowledge protected members(instance variables & methods) of a class are visible to same package classes and also to other package classes which inherit aforesaid class.

Strangely Eclipse is asking me to add protected keyword to the variables which are already protected. Please have a look of the screenshot also here [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJbNM.png)

I've cleaned & rebuilt the project and also restarted the eclipse.

I would appreciate if anyone can bridge the gap in my knowledge of java/eclipse/oops whichever I'm lacking here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compile error is right and I think you are just missing a little point!

`protected` access modifier means

1. If a class is defined like this:

   ```
   package com.j2se.access_specifiers;

   public class ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD {
       protected int protectedIntVar;
       protected String protectedStrVar;
   }
   ```

all the classes in the same package can access the `protected` fields **through its object** explicitly without any setter or getter methods.

2. All the **child** classes in other packages can access `protected` fields of **parent** class within their code, for example in their methods or constructor:

   ```
   public class ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD2 extends ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD{

       public ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD2() {
           protectedIntVar = 0;
           protectedStrVar = "Test";
       }
   }
   ```

But in your code you are creating an object from the parent class in the code of child class and this isn't supposed to work from the beginning.

**In short:**

If any object is created from your parent class only classes in the same package can access it through its object variable explicitly. In Other packages only children classes can access those `protected` fields of parent class explicitly in their methods or constructors.

Since `ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD2` extends `ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD` it will inherits **non-private** and **non-default** (without any modifier) fields of `ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD`. Then you can say `ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD2` has `protectedIntVar` and `protectedStrVar` fields as its own so it is obvious that you can access them through an object from `ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD2` since those fields are the fields of `ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD2` too:

```
ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD2 obj = new ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD2();
System.out.println( obj.protectedIntVar + " " + obj.protectedStrVar );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah seriously, thanks a lot! :) I missed that small point & got totally confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD2 obj = new ProtectedAccessSpecifierRnD2();
System.out.println(obj.protectedIntVar+" "+obj.protectedStrVar);
```

This should work